# Which context has the word "resilient" been used in here?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence which was:

> In a sense these variations are reflective of the complex processes that shaped early social histories --- through dialogues between dominant traditions and resilient local ideas and practices.

According to Merriam Webster dictionaries, it means -  tending to recover from or adjust easily to misfortune or change
But that doesn't fit here for me. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Weather Vane made a good point.

A resilient idea is strong, firm, and not easily damaged by being influenced.

A resilient idea can be profound or transcendent so it's hard to reason against it.

A resilient idea can be well-supported by the masses so it's challenging to prove it wrong.

> **This resilient idea** has led some historians to paint a completely false picture of these years.
>
> The entire work is driven relentlessly by **one resilient idea**.
>
> Nevertheless, expenditure taxation is **a resilient idea** that has become more and more popular in recent years.
>
> We can also understand how China, an ancient empire with a history of several thousand years, could retain **its resilient idea of "China"** throughout the turbulent changes in dynasties.